# Is there anything that non-newtonian calculus can do, which newtonian calculus cannot?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, problem-solving

As well, are there problems where non-newtonian calculus leads to a more elegant or simple solution than regular calculus?

Comment: Some hints here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_calculus#Reception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is nothing that non-Newtonian calculus can do that cannot be done with Newtonian calculus. The reason is that every non-Newtonian derivative or integral can be expressed using Newtonian derivatives or integrals respectively.  That said, I think there are problems where non-Newtonian calculus leads to a more elegant or simpler solution. A concrete example would be the well known Cole Hopf transformation that converts a nonlinear PDE into the linear heat equation.  The original non-linear PDE is only non-linear using Newtonian derivatives for the spatial variable. It is linear when using the so-called geometric derivatives for the spatial variable instead. I can give other examples.

Comment: More examples are always welcome!

Comment: This site lists many references, including a brief mention of the Cole Hopf application. https://sites.google.com/site/nonnewtoniancalculus/Home

Comment: Some nonlinear differential equations can be understood or solved via non-Newtonian derivatives. Pap's g calculus is very closely related to non-Newtonian calculus and has been applied this way.